# error: ‘hour’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, cmake

i wrote a code in c++. I tried to use CMake in Kdevelop.

for my header file Newtime.h

```
class NewTime
{
public:
  NewTime(int = 0, int = 0, int = 0);    //constructor
  void setTime(int, int, int);    // set time
  void dispTime();    //print time
private:
  int hour;
  int minute;
  int second;
};
```

for NewTime.cpp I wrote below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "NewTime.h"
//
NewTime::NewTime(int hr, int min, int sec)  
{
  setTime(hr, min, sec);
}
//
void NewTime::setTime(int h, int m, int s)
{
  hour = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
  minute = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
  second = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
}
//***
void Newtime::dispTime()
{
  std::cout << ((hour == 0 || hour == 12) ? 12 : hour % 12)
       << " : " << (minute < 10 ? "0" : "") << minute
       << " : " << (second < 10 ? "0" : "") << second
       << (hour < 12 ? " AM" : " PM") << std::endl;
}
```

and for main body is:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include "NewTime.h"

int main()
{
  NewTime t1, //use default arguments
          t2(2), //only hour defined
          t3(21, 34), //second as default
          t4(12, 25, 42), //everything is defined
          t5(53, 343, 234); //invalid hour
  std::cout << "constructed with: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "use default arguments: " << std::endl;
  t1.dispTime();
  std::cout << "only hour: " << std::endl;
  t2.dispTime();
  std::cout << "hour and minute: " << std::endl;
  t3.dispTime();
  std::cout << "all defined: " << std::endl;
  t4.dispTime();
  std::cout << "invalid values: " << std::endl;
  t5.dispTime();
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

but i got this errors:

```
compiling NewTime.cpp (c++)
/home/hasadi/Desktop/tmp/C++/4-6-class-newtimer/newtimer/NewTime.cpp:17: error: ‘Newtime’ has not been declared
/home/hasadi/Desktop/tmp/C++/4-6-class-newtimer/newtimer/NewTime.cpp: In function ‘void dispTime()’:
/home/hasadi/Desktop/tmp/C++/4-6-class-newtimer/newtimer/NewTime.cpp:19: error: ‘hour’ was not declared in this scope
/home/hasadi/Desktop/tmp/C++/4-6-class-newtimer/newtimer/NewTime.cpp:20: error: ‘minute’ was not declared in this scope
/home/hasadi/Desktop/tmp/C++/4-6-class-newtimer/newtimer/NewTime.cpp:21: error: ‘second’ was not declared in this scope
```

any idea? i got confused..

thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Please indent your code in future questions to make it more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo there, and the first error the compiler throws tells you:

```
[…]/NewTime.cpp:17: error: ‘Newtime’ has not been declared
```

You have to change `Newtime` in the dispTime-implementation to `NewTime` and it'll build. Right now, the compiler doesn't know that the dispTime implementation is associated with the `NewTime`-class.

In general, if you get `'varname' was not declared in this scope` inside method implementations, it's usually a missing or misspelled or the wrong class/struct type name.

As John Zwinck suggested in the comments, often **the first error is the most relevant**. You probably would've solved your problem by yourself by just looking at the first error.

Comment: And as a general point, when compiling C or C++ code, often the first error cascades to the rest of them, so the OP would have been well-served to just concentrate on the first part of the compilation error rather than the rest of it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks for the suggestion, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at your spelling!

```
void Newtime::dispTime()
{
std::cout << ((hour == 0 || hour == 12) ? 12 : hour % 12)
     << " : " << (minute < 10 ? "0" : "") << minute
     << " : " << (second < 10 ? "0" : "") << second
     << (hour < 12 ? " AM" : " PM") << std::endl;
}
```

You spelt it with a lowercase T!